# How do I get Version of all active plugins programmatically?

Tags: plugins, version-control

I want to check latest version of plugin is available or not. For that I required current version of active plugins. How can I get current version of all active plugins programmatically ?

Comment: `$`[`wp plugin list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/list/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem Analysis

To get information about installed plugins, which provides plugin's version, we'll use `get_plugins()` function. Keep in mind, that this function is available in back end only, so our code must reside there. Data, returned from this function, does not tell us, which plugins are active. To filter out active plugins, we'll use `get_option('active_plugins')` function. It will return a simple array, consisting of keys to array returned by `get_plugins()` function.

## Code

The best illustration for our method will be the actual code. We'll create a dashboard widget, displaying three-column table, showing active plugin's name, its current version, and its newest version in WordPress repository. Let's create `myDashboardWidget.php` file, and put the code below, in it.

```
<?php
if(is_admin()) { // make sure, the following code runs in back end

    // returns version of the plugin represented by $slug, from repository
    function getPluginVersionFromRepository($slug) {
        $url = "https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slugs][]={$slug}";
        $response = wp_remote_get($url); // WPOrg API call   
        $plugins = json_decode($response['body']);

        // traverse $response object
        foreach($plugins as $key => $plugin) {
            $version = $plugin->version;
        }
        return $version;
    }

    // dashboard widget's callback
    function activePluginsVersions() {
        $allPlugins = get_plugins(); // associative array of all installed plugins
        $activePlugins = get_option('active_plugins'); // simple array of active plugins

        // building active plugins table
        echo '<table width="100%">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th width="50%" style="text-align:left">Plugin</th>';
        echo '<th width="20%" style="text-align:left">currVer</th>';
        echo '<th width="20%" style="text-align:left">repoVer</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';

        // traversing $allPlugins array
        foreach($allPlugins as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($key, $activePlugins)) { // display active only
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td>{$value['Name']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$value['Version']}</td>";
                $slug = explode('/',$key)[0]; // get active plugin's slug

                // get newest version of active plugin from repository
                $repoVersion = getPluginVersionFromRepository($slug);

                echo "<td>{$repoVersion}</td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }     

    // widget's registration
    function fpwAddDashboardWidget() {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget(
            'active_plugins_versions', // widget's ID
            'Active Plugins Versions', // widget's title
            'activePluginsVersions'    // widget's callback (content)
        );  
    }
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'fpwAddDashboardWidget');
}
```

Now, place this file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` directory.

## Code Explained

Read comments within `myDashboardWidget.php` file.

**Note:** if there is no version shown in third column of the table, the plugin is not in repository (either premium, or discontinued).

## Code Efficiency

Efficiency of this sample code can be much improved. The WPOrg API request is made for each plugin. `/plugins/info/1.2/` version of the API, allows getting info for all plugin slugs with one request only.

Comment: This code works perfectly good .. One more thing if "currVer" is smaller than "repoVer" then it is obvious that update is required. But how can i know which files are changed or which files added new at repository side before update.

Comment: You can download the newest version from repository, and do 'diff' for your current version and downloaded version, to see what exactly is changed.

Comment: Yes I found download link from "$plugins" array .. But I want to know which files are changed before I update plugin.

Comment: I've explained it already. Download current plugin's folder to your local drive. Download the new version from repository and unzip to another folder. Use "Text diff" utility to see all differences.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get all active plugins.

In order to see an output of all your current active plugins to develop some code that might be different from mine, you can get a var_export for some test data as well with this:

```
if(is_admin())
{
    $allPlugins = get_plugins();
    $allActivePlugins = []; //prepare array for all Active plugins
    $activePlugins = get_option('active_plugins', array());
    foreach($allPlugins as $plugin => $pluginData)
    {
        //Wordpress made a function for this called "is_plugin_active" can be used as such: is_plugin_active($plugin)
        if(in_array($plugin, $activePlugins)) )
        {
            $allActivePlugins[$plugin] = $pluginData;
            echo 'Active plugin '.$pluginData['name'].' version: '.$pluginData['version'].'<br>';
            //Do something with the active plugin
        }

    }

    //List all active plugins in a var export
    echo '<pre>';
    echo var_export($allActivePlugins, true);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

In the foreach loop after the if statement, you can do something with each plugin.

Put this code any place where you want to output something in the wordpress admin area

Var Export output will output something like this

```
   array (
   'transients-manager/transients-manager.php' =>
       array (
       'Name' => 'Transients Manager',
       'PluginURI' => 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/',
       'Version' => '2.0.2',
       'Description' => 'Provides a familiar interface to view, search, edit, and delete Transients.',
       'Author' => 'WPBeginner',
       'AuthorURI' => 'https://www.wpbeginner.com',
       'TextDomain' => 'transients-manager',
       'DomainPath' => '',
       'Network' => false,
       'RequiresWP' => '5.3',
       'RequiresPHP' => '5.6.20',
       'UpdateURI' => '',
       'Title' => 'Transients Manager',
       'AuthorName' => 'WPBeginner',
       ),
   )
```

I felt like the accepted answer was a bit too long and there was a lot of code that just took up space and wasn't needed, adjust this code to your use case.

I also included a section for getting new versions.

### New versions for plugins

When it comes to getting available updates, Instead of the accepted answer, I recommend checking the transient called "update_plugins" which contains a list of currently available updates.

If any premium plugin has available updates, they will also put them here, there is literally no reason to query the Wordpress.org Plugin API since wordpress already does this for all plugins, you can force an update check by deleting the ('update_plugins') transient and reload any page via a browser, as it's populated with each load and I suspect it's through an ajax call,  so my suggestion is to do it with an Iframe as I haven't found where in the wordpress source code it makes this check and don't have time to further dig right now.

if you do this with custom code you just have more code to maintain instead of using  what's already available.

This is how to get the transient

```
$transient = get_transient('update_plugins');
```

To check for new updates, in the above code you go into the for each loop and you can do this:

```
if(isset($transient->response[$plugin]))
{
    //There is an update for this plugin
    $newInfo = $transient->response[$plugin];
    echo 'New version for plugin '.$newInfo->name.' version: '.$newInfo->new_version.'<br>';
}
```

The full code uses admin pages in this example, more about those here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Here is The full code from this would therefore be divided up into 2 files/pages, I have not included admin page code to make the code a bit more readable

```
<?php
delete_transient('update_plugins');
if(isset($_GET['is-transient-deleted']) && $_GET['is-transient-deleted'] == 1)
{
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?my-page-with-plugin-work'" />
<?
}
else
{
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?my-redirecter?is-transient-deleted=1'" />
<?php
}
```

```
if(is_admin())
{
    $allPlugins = get_plugins();
    $allActivePlugins = []; //prepare array for all Active plugins
    $activePlugins = get_option('active_plugins', array());
    $transient = get_transient('update_plugins');
    foreach($allPlugins as $plugin => $pluginData)
    {
        //Wordpress made a function for this called "is_plugin_active" can be used as such: is_plugin_active($plugin)
        if(in_array($plugin, $activePlugins)) )
        {
            $allActivePlugins[$plugin] = $pluginData;
            //Do something with the active plugin
            if(isset($transient->response[$plugin]))
            {
                //There is an update for this plugin
                $newInfo = $transient->response[$plugin];
                echo 'New version for plugin '.$newInfo->name.' version: '.$newInfo->new_version.'<br>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'No new version for plugin '.$pluginData['name'].' version: '.$pluginData['version'].'<br>';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
<?php 

// Check if get_plugins() function exists. This is required on the front end of the
// site, since it is in a file that is normally only loaded in the admin.
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

$all_plugins = get_plugins();
print_r( $all_plugins );
```

Hope this helps.