# Checking for a new version from WP Repos

Tags: version-control

I would like to know if there is a new version from the official WP Repos for a specific plugin.

How can I check for this in json/xml format? Or other format maybe?

Something like this: https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/

But for each single plugin in the WP repo

Comment: Check this question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354408/checking-update-status-and-getting-version-number-for-plugin-outside-of-the-word

Comment: @QStudio can't believe this. I though that as soon as they are uploaded into the WP Repo, WP repos update the version, and send the signal for new version availability, which somehow shall be querying some kind of API or simple signal from SVN repo, not sure...

Comment: Also the answers are weird: 100% of the plugins from WP Repos are auto-updated on newly released version, so maybe they are talking about plugins download outside from WP Repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, there is a JSON API.

Just had to dig a lot in the codex!

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins